# Display Category yearly wise in wp

Tags: categories, archives

How to list the categories yearly wise in template and the taxonomy page of the category should list the posts of the selected year.

```
2016                  2017          2018

Category 1           Category 2     Category 7
Category 2           Category 5     Category 1 
Category 5           Category 6     Category 8
```

Each category leads to the taxonomy page and there also the yearly filter must work.

Comment: Show us some code would help. Please don't expect we should chew code for you. WPSE is not a forum for requests, ppl here help you out with issues on coding.

Comment: I'm not asking for the code. Is it possible to do in a short way? I Can do this functionality by looping through all the posts for the unique years and categorize the post as array according to the category also. The code I have is for the listing categories and the taxonomy page looping posts.

Comment: Maybe taking a look [here](https://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-categories-by-year/) *some older but nice code from @bainternet* and/or maybe also [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=category+by+year)  and create a function using code found on those links?!